# php oci8 fetch array var

Tags: php, javascript, oracle, google-maps-api-3

I have an array in javascript that I want to post to php to store into oracle varchar2. I would like to know how to fetch this array in php. For now I always have a string [object Object] instead of the array in oracle. Im using JQuery $.post to send the variable to php like this:

```
function savePolygons(){
    $.get('oracle_deletePolygons.php');
    for (var i = 0; i < createdShapes.length; i++){
        var nom_zone  = escape(document.getElementById('nom_zone_' + createdShapes[i].id).value);
        var couleur = escape(createdShapes[i].fillColor);
        var code_cs = escape('711');
        var shapeid_export = escape(createdShapes[i].id);
        var geometry = createdShapes[i].getPath();
        alert(geometry)
        var url1 = "oracle_savePolygons.php?nom_zone=" + nom_zone + "&couleur=" + couleur + "&code_cs=" + code_cs + "&shapeid_export=" + shapeid_export + "&geometry=" + geometry;
        $.get(url1);
    }
}
```

in php:

```
<?php
require("oracle_dbinfo.php");
sleep(5);
$nom_zone =$_GET['nom_zone'];
$shapeid_export = $_GET['shapeid_export'];
$code_cs = $_GET['code_cs'];
$couleur = $_GET['couleur'];
$geometry = $_GET['geometry'];

$conn = oci_connect($username, $password, $database);
$query = oci_parse($conn, 'INSERT INTO test1 (nom_zone, shapeid, code_cs, couleur, geometry) VALUES (:nom_zone, :shapeid_export, :code_cs, :couleur, :geometry)');

oci_bind_by_name($query, ":nom_zone", $nom_zone);
oci_bind_by_name($query, ":shapeid_export", $shapeid_export);
oci_bind_by_name($query, ":code_cs", $code_cs);
oci_bind_by_name($query, ":couleur", $couleur);
oci_bind_by_name($query, ":geometry", $geometry);

oci_execute($query);
oci_commit($conn);
?>
```

the var geometry is an array of coordinates of each vertices of the polygon.

Comment: Why are you using `$.post()` then why are you building a parameter string as used for GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use $.get() if your not posting any data to the url:

```
$.get('oracle_deletePolygons.php');
```

Please refer to [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Also note this should most likely be using $.get() because your just sending querystrings:

```
var url1 = "oracle_savePolygons.php?nom_zone=" + nom_zone + "&couleur=" + couleur + "&code_cs=" + code_cs + "&shapeid_export=" + shapeid_export + "&geometry=" + geometry;
$.post(url1);
```

Try this instead:

```
var url1 = "oracle_savePolygons.php?nom_zone=" + nom_zone + "&couleur=" + couleur + "&code_cs=" + code_cs + "&shapeid_export=" + shapeid_export + "&geometry=" + geometry;
$.get(url1);
```

Example of posting data using [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
$.get('oracle_savePolygons.php', {
    'num_zone' : nom_zone,
    'couleur' : couleur,
    'code_cs' : code_cs,
    'shapeid_export' : shapeid_export,
    'geometry' : geometry
}, function (data) {
  //Success callback if you need it
});
```

Comment: In fact the data are not posted in oracle_deletePolygons.php, but in oracle_savePolygons.php. oracle_deletePolygons.php just delete all records of the oracle table.

Comment: Ok, so I cant use querystrings for array. How to post it?